# warning: field never read locally

Tags: java, list, generics

I would like to understand why this warning is displayed in my code and how I could fix it

Edit: (for some reason my code was not displayed correctly, sorry about that. I used backspace to make the generics visible.)

```
class LinkedSortedAppendList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements SortedAppendList<T>{

    private class ListCell {
        T content;
        ListCell prev;
        ListCell next;

        ListCell(T v, ListCell p, ListCell n) {
            this.content = v;
            this.prev = p;
            this.next = n;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share the complete code.

Comment: This is clearly an inner class. Please show more context. If we remove `private` and add `<T>` after the `class ListCell` (e.g., make it compile as a non-inner class), there are no compiler warnings. More: [mcve]

Comment: thanks for your answer, I edited my code because it was not displayed correctly. If i add <T> then I'll get the "is hiding the type" warning.  Also, I was told that inner list cell classes should always be encapsulated so its necessary to declare them as private isn't it?  And since I'm using the same T as in the outer class it's not necessary to add <T> there right?

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned ListCell class as private, that means it's visible to only it's top level class. So scope of it's usage is within that class, if you are not using it within that class, you will receive this warning.

Comment: ok that makes sense, but I was told that inner list cell classes should be made private because of the encapsulation principle. Is there any way to solve this without "breaking" this principle?

Comment: If the usage of your inner class is just confined to its top level class, and no other class is using it, then it make sense to keep it private. But if you have not used it, in it's top level class, then it has no purpose, no other class will have access to it.